# How to do this in twig format?

Tags: php, twig

This one:

```
value="<?php echo isset($quantity_taxation_sort_order) ? $quantity_taxation_sort_order : '' ?>"
```

to become in twig format. I tried with this one, but it's not correct:

```
value="{{ quantity_taxation_sort_order is defined ? quantity_taxation_sort_order : '' }}"
```

Comment: [Your code should work as is](https://twigfiddle.com/3jb5wc)

Answer (score 0):

Print it using twig if statement:

```
value="{% if quantity_taxation_sort_order %}{{ quantity_taxation_sort_order }}{% endif %}"
```

or in case of strict twig mode:

```
value="{% if quantity_taxation_sort_order is defined %}{{ quantity_taxation_sort_order }}{% endif %}"
```

More info on [Twig documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tests/defined.html).

Comment: without "is defined" ?

Comment: dont put logic in your view files

Comment: @delboy1978uk Uau, why not? How can I hide part of HTML if I don't use logic? Just for example.

Comment: i'm not, i'm suggesting the best practice when using twig is to use their twig extensions

Answer (score 0):

I found this way:

```
value="{{ (quantity_taxation_sort_order is defined) ? quantity_taxation_sort_order : '' }}"
```

Answer (score -5):

Twig is a view file templating engine. Separate your concerns!

Business Logic **doesn't belong** in a view. Echoes and loops are the only real code a view file should contain. So the correct way to do it is, either:

1. Generate the output in PHP, then pass the output to the twig layout for echoing.
2. Create a twig extension file, and call the twig function, which will do the business logic.

Here's a sample Twig Extension from their documentation:

```
namespace AppBundle\Twig;

class AppExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFilter('price', array($this, 'priceFilter')),
        );
    }

    public function priceFilter($number, $decimals = 0, $decPoint = '.', $thousandsSep = ',')
    {
        $price = number_format($number, $decimals, $decPoint, $thousandsSep);
        $price = '$'.$price;

        return $price;
    }
}
```

Check the docs out here! https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html

Comment: This has nothing to do with business logic though

Comment: an if statement is a logical operator. MUCH better just looping and echoing

Comment: @delboy1978uk everything except printing is logic, including looping. So you are very, very offtopic here! In Twig, everytime you need `{% %}` you are dealing with logic!

Comment: logic with no complexity

Comment: A Twig function isn't exactly business domain either. Also, Twig can manipulate data, if something is empty do something else. It's a template/view, not dumb output dumper. Sure complex things should be passed to it, but don't format your view outputs in PHP land as that is bad.